# Selecionando checkbox direto do console

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dúvida, eu preciso selecionar vários checkbox automáticos para ficar mais rápido o processo de criar um novo usuário.

Porém não sei o que fazer.

Coloquei o seguinte código no console e ele retorna erro, códigos abaixo

```
document.getElementTagName("input").checked = true;
```

Meu input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="common/security">
```

Erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementTagName is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:10
```

Qual seria a função mais adequada para realizar esse procedimento? Posso utilizar tanto pela tag, quanto pelo name ou por value. Isso não importa

Agradeço desde já

Comment: A função getElementTagName não existe. O correto seria getElementsByTagName que retorna um array de elementos.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, se quiser formular uma resposta para eu dar correto, vou criar outra pergunta com uma dúvida um pouco mais profunda sobre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além do que comentou o amigo Ghert, de que o correto é `getElementsByTagName`, há outro ponto a observar. Como essa função retorna um *nodelist* (ou um array com os elementos que possuam a tag especificada), é preciso também especificar o índice da tag.

Por exemplo, se quiser que o primeiro elemento com a tag `input` seja alterado, use o índice `[0]`:

```
                                      ↓↓↓
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = true;
```

Se você não colocar um índice, nada irá acontecer ao elemento.

Porém, o mais indicado é usar um seletor mais específico, isso porque a tag `input` abrange outros tipos de elementos e não apenas `checkbox`. O ideal mesmo, ao meu ver, era usar:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")[0].checked = true;
```

O `document.querySelectorAll` é um método mais específico e flexível, onde você pode selecionar o elemento pela tag e pelo tipo ao mesmo tempo. Desta forma você pode selecionar apenas os inputs checkbox, e não qualquer input.

Ressaltando que esse método também retorna um *nodelist*, sendo necessário indicar o índice desejado, onde `[0]` é o primeiro, `[1]` o segundo e por aí vai.

Agora, se você tiver apenas 1 elemento checkbox, pode usar `document.querySelector`, que diferentemente do `document.querySelectorAll`, irá pegar apenas o primeiro elemento que encontrar, e como não retorna um *nodelist*, não precisa de índice:

```
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").checked = true;
```